# how to get result of a function as string with ajax in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm developing a plugin for wordpress and I want to use ajax in it. lets say I have the following function:

```
function ajax_say_hello(){
    return "hello";
}
```

I want to get the result of ajax_say_hello() as a string with ajax. something like "hello".
to do this, I added the following:
in my plugins function.php >

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_say_hello', 'ajax_say_hello');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_say_hello', 'ajax_say_hello' );
```

and in my ajax.js >

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
          var data = {
              action: 'ajax_say_hello',
          };

          jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
              alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
          });
      });
});
```

and ajaxurl is defined correctly. 
but I get the entire page as result with no error in console. what is wrong here and what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_say_hello', 'ajax_post_ajax_say_hello');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_say_hello', 'ajax_post_ajax_say_hello' );
function ajax_post_ajax_say_hello(){
    echo "hello";
    die;
}
```

Comment: tnx. no differences, I have the same result as before. your code just have die comparing to my code.

Comment: No, my code is different. your call back `ajax_say_hello` function is not right. it should be `ajax_post_ajax_say_hello`

Comment: I tested my code and working fine for me.

Comment: sorry, I changed it but I get the same result. and I've updated the post.

Comment: can you share the page link?